# How load files added dinamically before call other js file that needs one of that files

Tags: javascript

First of all, give thanks for reading my question and try to help me and apologize for my English.

I have the following problem...

I'm adding js file and css file dinamically, but sometimes appears an error because load first a static js file before that downlod both files added dinamically.

How can solve that problem? 
Until download both files added dynamically, do not load the js file (mapfunctions.js)

My api js file, call a function where add dinamically js file and css file as you can see.

This is my index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Map Generator</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    // this file add dinamically a js file and a css file
    <script src="./js/api/api.js"></script>
    // this file needs js file added dinamically, and if is not downloaded crash
    <script src="./js/option2/mapfunctions.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:50%; height:50%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
            customMap.addMap("5b4f12233cfb101f4c2d0537", "map");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error that shows sometimes is: 
`Error: ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined at Object.createMap`

This is my api.js file:

```
let mapboxJsUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.js';
let mapboxCssUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.css';

(function(window, document) {

    var includeJSFiles = function(url) {
        var apiJs = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script.setAttribute("src", url);

        var css = includeCss(mapboxCssUrl);
        if (apiJs !== undefined) {
            head.insertBefore(script, apiJs);
        } else {
            head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
        }
        head.insertBefore(css, script);
    };

    var includeCss = function(url) {
        var css = document.createElement("link");
        css.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        css.setAttribute("href", url);

        return css;
    };

    includeJSFiles(mapboxJsUrl);

}(window, document));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, your safest bet may be to use the `load` event on the `window` object. [According to MDN,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) `load` is only fired when all resources and dependencies have loaded so that may make it a better fit for your situation.

I'm not familiar with mapbox, however [after a little research](https://jsfiddle.net/wy5rdwzz/) I found that the api your trying to use will create a `mapboxgl` object in your `window context`.

Seeing as `customMap` is not defined anywhere, I instead checked for the existence of `mapboxgl` on `window` to verify that the Mapbox API was dynamically loading into your sample. I made the following adjustments to your code to achieve dynamically loaded mapbox scripts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Map Generator</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    // this file add dinamically a js file and a css file
    <script src="./js/api/api.js"></script>
    // this file needs js file added dinamically, and if is not downloaded crash
    <script src="./js/option2/mapfunctions.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:50%; height:50%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
    /* UPDATE
       Add event listener to window object, and register handler on the load event
    */
    window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        customMap.addMap("5b4f12233cfb101f4c2d0537", "map");
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, in your `api.js` script, you should make the following adjustments to faciliate this:

```
(function(window, document) {

    var includeJSFiles = function(url) {
        //var apiJs = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script.setAttribute("src", url);

        // UPDATE
        // Keep this simple, and insert the script as head's first node
        head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);

        var css = includeCss(mapboxCssUrl);
        head.insertBefore(css, script);
    };

    var includeCss = function(url) {
        var css = document.createElement("link");
        css.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        css.setAttribute("href", url);

        return css;
    };

    includeJSFiles(mapboxJsUrl);

}(window, document));
```

Hope this helps you!